# React & Redux: Render child component outside parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have 2 main panels. Left panel for navigation and it has a list of items. One I select one item, will populate right pane with item details.

For example, in the left panel, I could have a list of persons names. Once a person is selected, the right panel will not be empty any more and will contain more details: address, age,...

What I did so far, When selecting an item fro list, fire redux action with `selectedId`. Inside right panel, listen to redux changes and if `selectedId` is not empty, render item details.

This approach works fine. But, I think It could be improved. If I have the right panel as a child component of selected item in the left component, It should work without dealing with redux actions at all.
However, the only issue is, How to display details component on the right panel as a child but not rendered inside list item?

Am I on the right direction?

How can I implement such scenario?

Comment: You can use portals (check React documentation) but it might be that your design is slightly wrong, why the right panel has to be created in an outer component if it's always driven by the inner one? Alternatively you can put the data you need in the redux state and the right panel it's responsible of their rendering (this definitely won't scale well if you have more than two different types there)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti As you said. I have a more list type(persons, products, cars,...) and from the left panel I have dropdwon to switch types and select one item. and the right panel will be common and will display details based on list type and selected item. So the only reason to not have right panel as child of left panel is to avoid duplication

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code but: I do not imagine any duplication, your right panel has to be a control on its own (with all the shared - not duplicate - code) and each list will put the appropriate content inside it. Also note that it's really easy to do it with routing. Prepare different controls for `PersonDetails`, `CarDetails` and use the URL (with `Switch` and `Route`) to instantiate the correct one: `/users/:id` and `/cars/:id`.